# How to merge multiple column headers in a javascript Prime Vue data table

Tags: javascript, datatables, primevue

I am trying to create a Data Table in Prime Vue with merge columns. Below is a mockup I made in Excel with what the headers should be.

[table header mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8XYg.png)

Also, my reference is the [documentation on column group](https://primevue.org/datatable/#column_group)

However when I try to place multiple merged column groups or even individual ones, I cannot seem to add or see them.

[here is a StackBlitz demo that I am using:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pfandb?file=src%2FApp.vue)

As you can see, when I added colspan the merge works as intended:

```
<ColumnGroup type="header">
<Row>
    <Column header="C1" :rowspan="3" />
    <Column header="C2" :rowspan="3" />
    <Column header="C3" :rowspan="3" />
    <Column header="C4" :rowspan="3" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Column header="L1" :colspan="2" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Column header="C5"/>
    <Column header="C6"/>
</Row>
</ColumnGroup>
```

But I am not sure how other columns can show up, how do I fix this?

what I tried:

- added `<Column header="C7"></Column>` after the ColumnGroup tag. It did not show up.
- also tried the above but within the ColumnGroup tag, same result.
- added another separate ColumnGroup tag and tried placing the regular columns there. no results.